# Basic php Login form with defined Name and Password

Tags: php

I am a beginner in Php programming . I have been trying to create a basic Login form with a fixed username and password in a if loop , The first time i run the program i get a warning for the if-else loop which i cant figure it out but it runs perfectly.
I want to show an error below the submit when i enter a wrong password or username . I cant figure out how to do that .

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#login
{

    position:absolute;
    top: 30%;
    bottom: 30%;
    left:30%;
    right:30%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width:auto;
    height:600px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo"<center>";
echo"<div id=\"login\">";

echo"<form method=\"POST\">";
echo"<b>Username</b>  <input type =\"text\" name=\"username\">";
echo"<br/><br/>";
echo"<b>Password</b>&nbsp;<input type =\"password\" name=\"password\">";
echo"<br/><br/>";
echo"<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\">";

echo"</div>";
echo"</center>";

if($_POST['username'] =="user" && $_POST['password']=="user")
  {
   header("Location: contact.php");

   }
 else 
 {
  // i want to display an error when clicking submit 
  }
   ?>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Use `isset()` and `empty()` to check if the variables are set. If not, bail out.

Comment: Don't start learning to code with authentication. Use a peer-reviewed open source library.

Comment: Yikes, the big `echo` blocks and pile of escaped quotes makes me think you'll have a hard time maintaining this in the future. See my profile if you want to work through an online tutorial book to show you how to do this correctly (i.e. presentation/logic separation, login handling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you run this script, the `$_POST['username']` (and password) isn't defined.

What you have to do is check if it's defined like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] == "user" && isset($_POST['password']) &&  $_POST['password']=="user")
```

[Here's an link about the isset function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Also, do the check on top of the page. Because you'r already sending content, your redirect won't work.

*header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP*

Comment: It is better to have two if statements in this case, as you will end up with an error message even when someone did not have a password submitted in this case.

Comment: @Digits I agree with you that it would be nicer (better readable) to have 2 if statements. But i disagree with the error message. Because if somebody doesn't submit something, the `isset` function will make sure you step out of the if statement. Otherwise there would be something (even nothing is something in PHP) to compare to, so there wouldn't be an error

Comment: If the user doesn't submit something (IE: you visit the page for the first time) you will have a message popping up saying "your username or password is incorrect" from the linked else statement, despite not submitting anything. This is the true reason for 2 if statements, so that it may check that the user is actually trying to do something, before telling them that they're doing it wrong.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding you. You're totally right on that point.

Answer (score 1):

First check that you really have some $_POST data:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // then check your username and password
    if($_POST['username'] =="user" && $_POST['password']=="user")
    {
        header("Location: contact.php");
    }
    else 
    {
        // display error
    }
}
```